# Knockout doesn't react to jquery events

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have an app using **KnockoutJS** with a simple input `<input id="name" data-bind="value: name">` and `this.name = ko.observable()` in my ViewModel.

When I do `$('#name').val('test').trigger('change')`, the value of the input in the DOM is updated but it doesn't update the binding `this.name`.

Anything I should configure to make knockout react to jquery events?

Comment: @AdamWolski Same with textInput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provided actually works. Consider the code below. Note, that you must execute jQuery code after bindings have been applied.

```js
const test = ko.observable('');
ko.applyBindings({test});

ko.computed(function(){
  console.log(test());
});

$('input').val('wow').trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" data-bind="value: test">
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like the order of the script is important